# How to disable localhost_access_log files for ColdFusion/Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, coldfusion-10, coldfusion-11

I was running out of disk space on a web server.  Since the logs are stored on another drive and there wasn't any new files for the web sites, there had to be something else going on.

I found that the Tomcat service that comes with ColdFusion 10 was writing log files for every web page request in this folder {ColdFusion Root}\cfusion\runtime\logs.  They accounted for 8GB of disk space!

The filenames were in this format: localhost_access_log.YYYY-MM-DD.txt

If you are running a single site on your ColdFusion server, this may be OK.  The problem with the log files is that they only display the SCRIPT_NAME and QUERY_STRING for the request.  You won't be able to tell which site the "/index.cfm" request is for.  Maybe it can be configured to include the site hostname.

I would rather disable this logging as IIS logging is more informative.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edit this file:
{ColdFusion Root}\cfusion\runtime\conf\server.xml

Find this line:

```
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false"/>
```

Comment out the line like this:

```
    <!-- <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
           prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" resolveHosts="false"/> -->
```

Save the file.

Restart the ColdFusion service.

Comment: Just FYI for people out there: same goes for regular Tomcat (not running on ColdFusion)