# Tomcat localhost_access_log files cleanup

Tags: tomcat, logging

We have Solr running on Tomcat 8. We are having issues in our different environments with localhost_access_log files filling up the servers. These files are created by the Access Valve Log in server.xml configured like this -

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
   prefix="localhost_access_log" 
   suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

From what I've read, there is no OOTB way in Tomcat to clean up old log files. What can I implement to clean up the old access log files?

Comment: possible in tomcat 9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have a log rotation and then choose what logs files to delete

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt" rotatable="true" renameOnRotate="true" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

As rotation is set to true by default you should already have it. Then you can for exemple delete logs older than 5 days:

To delete log files older than 10 days the following commands can be used.

```
Unix
find /path/to/httplogs/ -name "*.log" -type f -mtime +10 -exec rm -f {} \;

For Windows Server OS:
forfiles /p "C:\path\to\httplogs" /s /m *.log /d -10 /c "cmd /c del @PATH"
```

Comment: The windows command works great! Any risk with using *.*. The tomcat files are configured as suffix of txt.

Comment: Just change the wildcard if you are afraid of deleting wrong files

Answer (score 10):

In theory you don't have to do it manually. Set this property in your `config/server.xml` and the server will clean for you automatically.

```
maxDays="10"
```

Example configuration line:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
   prefix="localhost_access_log" 
   suffix=".txt" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"
   maxDays="10" />
```

Then restart your `tomcat` / `tomcat8` / `tomcat9` service.

Comment: Please make sure to use double quotes around the value for maxDays i.e. maxDays="10", otherwise Tomcat will thrown an error when trying to parse the value.

Answer (score 2):

You can [disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669996/how-to-disable-localhost-access-log-files-for-coldfusion-tomcat) localhost_access log by commenting configuration line.

or

In linux, set daily [cron job](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/) to delete old files.

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/your/script/cleanup.sh
```

**cleanup.sh**

```
#This will remove files older than a week.
find /TOMCAT_HOME/logs -name "localhost_access_log*.txt" -type f -mtime +7 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: I implemented a cron to delete the access logs but the problem is the tomcat does not release memory until it is restarted.