# Removing older http_access logs - WSO2 APIM 3.2.0 and WSO2 IS 5.11.0

Tags: tomcat, wso2, log4j2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am using `WSO2 APIM 3.2.0` and `WSO2 IS 5.11.0`.

I have logs in directory `${sys:carbon.home}/repository/logs/`

I could manage the log growth by removing the older files more than 30 days by adding the below configuration in `${sys:carbon.home}/repository/conf/log4j2.properties`

```
appender.ERROR_LOGFILE.strategy.action.type = Delete
appender.ERROR_LOGFILE.strategy.action.basepath = 
${sys:carbon.home}/repository/logs/
appender.ERROR_LOGFILE.strategy.action.maxdepth = 1
appender.ERROR_LOGFILE.strategy.action.condition.type = IfLastModified
appender.ERROR_LOGFILE.strategy.action.condition.age = 30D
appender.ERROR_LOGFILE.strategy.action.PathConditions.type = IfFileName
appender.ERROR_LOGFILE.strategy.action.PathConditions.glob = wso2-apigw-errors-*
```

I can do the same for wso2carbon, audit logs but the log4j2.properties has no support for http_access logs.

In `${sys:carbon.home}/repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml`, AccessLogValve has control for http_access logs.

I am not sure how to remove the older logs using this XML file.
Can someone let me know how it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

As you have correctly identified org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve is used to log http access logs.

If you want to delete the access log file older than 30 days, this option can be used https://stackoverflow.com/a/57826692/10055162.

Navigate to `<IS-HOME>/repository/resources/conf/templates/repository/conf/carbon.xml.j2` and add property `maxDays="30"` to AccessLogValve as follows. Then restart the server.

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="${carbon.home}/repository/logs"
                       prefix="http_access_" suffix=".log" pattern="{{http_access_log.pattern}}"  maxDays="30" />
```

Since these configs adding is not templated, you can't do the configuration via deployment.toml

More info about the property:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html

Comment: I added the property maxDays="30" to AccessLogValve and restarted the server, after the restart, the changes are not seen, it is vanished.

Comment: did you change carbon.xml.j2 or carbon.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 Identity Server 5.11.0 has got the capability to configure the HTTP access logs from log4j.properties file itself. While this is not available in the documentation yet, you have to follow below instructions to configure this.

Add below lines to `deployment.toml` file

```
[http_access_log]
useLogger = true
```

This will enable the capability to control the access logs from `log4j2.properties` file. Follow below instructions to change the configurations in `log4j2.properties` file.

1. Add HTTP_ACCESS to the existing "appenders"

   `appenders = CARBON_CONSOLE, CARBON_LOGFILE, AUDIT_LOGFILE, ATOMIKOS_LOGFILE, CARBON_TRACE_LOGFILE, DELETE_EVENT_LOGFILE, TRANSACTION_LOGFILE, osgi, HTTP_ACCESS`
2. Add HTTP_ACCESS to existing "loggers"

   `loggers = HTTP_ACCESS, AUDIT_LOG, trace-messages, org-apache-coyote, com-hazelcast, Owasp-CsrfGuard, org-apache-axis2-wsdl-codegen-writer-PrettyPrinter, org-apache-axis2-clustering, org-apache-catalina, org-apache-tomcat, org-wso2-carbon-apacheds, org-apache-directory-server-ldap, org-apache-directory-server-core-event, com-atomikos, org-quartz, org-apache-jackrabbit-webdav, org-apache-juddi, org-apache-commons-digester-Digester, org-apache-jasper-compiler-TldLocationsCache, org-apache-qpid, org-apache-qpid-server-Main, qpid-message, qpid-message-broker-listening, org-apache-tiles, org-apache-commons-httpclient, org-apache-solr, me-prettyprint-cassandra-hector-TimingLogger, org-apache-axis-enterprise, org-apache-directory-shared-ldap, org-apache-directory-server-ldap-handlers, org-apache-directory-shared-ldap-entry-DefaultServerAttribute, org-apache-directory-server-core-DefaultDirectoryService, org-apache-directory-shared-ldap-ldif-LdifReader, org-apache-directory-server-ldap-LdapProtocolHandler, org-apache-directory-server-core, org-apache-directory-server-ldap-LdapSession, DataNucleus, Datastore, Datastore-Schema, JPOX-Datastore, JPOX-Plugin, JPOX-MetaData, JPOX-Query, JPOX-General, JPOX-Enhancer, org-apache-hadoop-hive, hive, ExecMapper, ExecReducer, net-sf-ehcache, axis2Deployment, equinox, tomcat2, StAXDialectDetector, org-apache-directory-api, org-apache-directory-api-ldap-model-entry, TRANSACTION_LOGGER, DELETE_EVENT_LOGGER, org-springframework, org-opensaml-xml-security-credential-criteria, org-wso2-carbon-user-core, org-wso2-carbon-identity, org-wso2-carbon-identity-sso-saml`
3. Add configurations of newly added logger and appender (you can change the values as required).

   ```
   logger.HTTP_ACCESS.level = INFO
   logger.HTTP_ACCESS.appenderRef.HTTP_ACCESS.ref = HTTP_ACCESS
   logger.HTTP_ACCESS.additivity = false

   # Appender for HTTP Access Log
   appender.HTTP_ACCESS.type = RollingFile
   appender.HTTP_ACCESS.name = HTTP_ACCESS
   appender.HTTP_ACCESS.fileName =${sys:carbon.home}/repository/logs/http_access.log
   appender.HTTP_ACCESS.filePattern =${sys:carbon.home}/repository/logs/http_access-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log
   appender.HTTP_ACCESS.layout.type = PatternLayout
   appender.HTTP_ACCESS.layout.pattern = [%X{Correlation-ID}] %mm%n
   appender.HTTP_ACCESS.policies.type = Policies
   appender.HTTP_ACCESS.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
   appender.HTTP_ACCESS.policies.time.interval = 1
   appender.HTTP_ACCESS.policies.time.modulate = true
   appender.HTTP_ACCESS.policies.size.type = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy
   appender.HTTP_ACCESS.policies.size.size=10MB
   appender.HTTP_ACCESS.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
   appender.HTTP_ACCESS.strategy.max = 20
   appender.HTTP_ACCESS.filter.threshold.type = ThresholdFilter
   appender.HTTP_ACCESS.filter.threshold.level = INFO
   ```

You can refer to [this](https://github.com/wso2/docs-is/issues/1615) documentation ticket created to add the feature to the documentation.

Comment: line `logger.HTTP_ACCESS.name = HTTP_ACCESS` is missing

Comment: by the way I can't get it working when using WSO2 APIM 4.0.0 - the file is populated only when `additivity = true`, but in this case carbon.log and container's stdout also get flooded